# Rails - Simple Forms - undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller, simple-form-for

I am trying to make a form where you select tables that you want to export. I made a simple form with a list of tables that can be exported. My plan was to allow the user to toggle check boxes for the tables they want to export and as a result they would be able to download a zip file containing the tables.

Currently, when I try to go to the page with the form, I get an error:

`undefined method 'model_name' for nil:NilClass`

The majority of the usage of simple forms that I see online consists of using forms to create new items to save in their models. As a result, it seems that the line `simple_form_for @example` would mean that when the user clicks the submit button, there is a line in the controller such as `@example = SomeClass.new"`. My understanding is that the user input of the form is saved in @example and can be used by the controller. However, as I am not creating a new item in the model, I just want to use the values from @example, I am not sure what to put in the controller to get rid of the error so that I can code the rest of the function in the controller.

Controller:

```
class FormController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @options = []
    print(@options)
  end

end
```

The form used:

```
<h2>Which tables do you want to export?</h2>
<div class="well">
  <% tables_in_model = %w(Table1 Table2 Table3) %>
  <%= simple_form_for @selected_options, :url => form_index_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :options, as: :check_boxes, collection: tables_in_model %>
    <%= f.button :submit, as: :Submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag if you think your form data does not belong to an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said correctly in your question, **`simple_form` should be used to render forms to the user when her actions are related to the creation or edition of ActiveRecord models.**

For instance, when writing down code to enable a search feature, where your goal is to simply pass a bunch of user chosen params to a controller, you should not use it. I believe you are in a similar position with the feature you described.

**Simple solution though: use [rails form related DSL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to get your form going!**

Hope it's the answer you needed. Feel free to ask for more details if needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using **simple_form**  you need to specify like 
`@selected_options = SelectedOptionModel.new(params)` 
into your controller
then it passes into View. 
if you don't have any model you can use **form_tag**

like this:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

this will create html form like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" method="get">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <label for="q">Search for:</label>
  <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```